# How to restore libusb-* after using rm -rf libusb-*?

Tags: drivers, gnome

How to restore libusb-* after using rm -rf libusb-*?

It removed > 100mb including nvidia etc. drivers and now I end up only with a terminal which I can log into. Gnome desktop isn't available anymore?

Comment: This will not remove anything, unless the files libusb-* are in the current directory. In general, a `rm` cannot be restored - you have to replace new copies of the deleted files.

Comment: What directory were you in when you ran this command?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `apt-file search libusb | grep .so` or `apt-file search libusb` or `apt search libusb` you will see a number of packages providing the files you removed. Here are some specific ones that caught my attention on my system:

```
libusb-0.1-4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4
libusb-0.1-4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
libusb-1.0-0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
libusb-1.0-0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0.2.0
```

You can do: `sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0` and that will install that package. Process the output of the aforementioned commands, go through each `libusb*` in the output and you can install the package by specifying the package name to `apt`.

Comment: It might make more sense to run something like `dpkg -S "$PWD/libusb-*"` in the directory where they ran the original `rm` command - that will limit the results to packages that are currently installed on the system and that provided files that may have been deleted